# Nested for-cycles in Django templates

Tags: django, for-loop, neomodel

I am using Django my a NoSQL graph database, and the Neomodel binding to link them. Querying it in my local shell, I have everything correct:

```
city = PlaceName.index.search(name='Sargans')

for x in city:
    results = x.traverse('hasid')
    for  y in results:
        print x.name, x.type, y.loc_id
   ...:         
Sargans orig loc000928
Sargans std loc000010
Sargans orig loc000010
Sargans orig loc000654
Sargans std loc000925
Sargans orig loc000063
Sargans orig loc000011
Sargans orig loc000929
```

I want to get the same output through my Django-app, but what I get is:

```
Sargans orig loc000929
Sargans std loc000929
Sargans orig loc000929
Sargans orig loc000929
Sargans std loc000929
Sargans orig loc000929
Sargans orig loc000929
Sargans orig loc000929
```

As if the second loop goes over the same entity every time...

PlaceName class:

```
class PlaceName(StructuredNode):
    name = StringProperty(index=True, required=True)
    lang = StringProperty(index=True, required=True)
    type = StringProperty(index=True, required=True)#std/orig
    hasid = RelationshipTo('PlaceId', 'HAS_ID')
    descr = RelationshipTo('Desc', 'HAS_DESC')
```

In my views.py:

```
placenames = PlaceName.index.search(name=q)
for x in placenames:
    results = x.traverse('hasid')

return render_to_response('search_results.html',
                                      {'placenames':placenames, 'query':q, 'res':results})
```

In my templates:

```
{% for x in placenames %}
   {% for y in res %}

 <a>   {{ x.name }} {{ x.type  }} {{ y.loc_id }} </a><br></li>

    % endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

How to write the correct template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the full list of results **for each placename**.

In views.py:

```
places = [{'placename': x, 'results': x.traverse('hasid')} for x in placenames]
return render_to_response('search_results.html', {'places': places})
```

In the template:

```
{% for x in places %}
    {% for y in x.results %}
        <a>   {{ x.placename.name }} {{ x.placename.type  }} {{ y.loc_id }} </a><br></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You are the saviour of my day! Thank you very much, it works perfectly!!